# Unity Correct Sprite/Texture Width Height

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, sprite, projection

I discovered something interesting about Unity `Sprite` and textures (`Texture2D`). I crated a 50x50 `.png` and render it in Unity by attaching to a `GameObject` and using `SpriteRenderer`.

What I realized, whenever I call a Unity related method (`sprite.texture.width`, `sprite.rect.width`, `sprite.textureRect.width`, etc.), it always return 50. However, the real size of the image turns into 24x24 or 12x12 depending on the resolution on my screen.

Of course, this is no big surprise since the projection, etc. is applied before Unity render the things on the screen; however, the interesting part I couldn't find any method or easy way to get the size of the `Sprite` after the projection is applied.

I can still make my own projection to come up with the related size; however, I would like to know whether there is an easier way to get this information.

Thank you!

Comment: That's...not an easy question to answer. The image could be inside a transform with a scale applied, etc etc. But you *can* convert from scene units to screen coordinates. So if you know where the corners are, you can do `Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(corner)` can calculate from that.

Comment: I could be wrong, but the 'real' size of the image that is rendered depends on your screen resolution, the camera size and the PPU value of the sprite.

Comment: @Draco18s it's not working well. I tried with sprite.rect.max to world space and it returned (-7.3, -4.0) instead (-4.166, -4.166)

Comment: `sprite.rect.max` is UV coordinates of the sprite in its underlying texture, they are completely and utterly the wrong thing to use here. You need the corners of the sprite's *`RectTransform`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way @Draco18s mentioned seems the only way to solve this problem.

So, I crated a `Prefab` `GameObject` containing `RectTransform` and `SpriteRenderer`, and got the width and height as below:

```
GameObject twoSide = Instantiate(Resources.Load(mFilePath + "Locater")) as GameObject;

twoSide.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (0, 0, 1));
twoSide.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().pivot = new Vector2 (0f, 0f);    // RectTransform should have the same pivot location with Sprite

float width = twoSide.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().offsetMax.x - twoSide.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().offsetMin.x;
float height = twoSide.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().offsetMax.y - twoSide.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().offsetMin.y;
```